Blender 3.4 coordinates in file unable to move objects
I just ran into this problem with an old file, where there are large coordinates in my viewport when I select an object, and when I try to move that object only the coordinates move and not the object itself. Does anyone know how to turn this off or switch it? I've opened a new file in 3.4 and didn't have this issue (it seemed to be working like normal) so I must have accidently turned something on in my file last time I used it but I can't imagine what.


Thank you for any help or guidance!
